# How do you secure a power function motor to a technic extreme cruiser?

Tags: technic, power-functions, set-modification

I am trying to help my son install a power function m motor in his Technic extreme cruiser.  We found a good place to put the motor and if we hold it in place it does drive the rear wheels.

The problem we are having is figuring out how to secure the motor to the car so that it stays in place when we operate it via the remote control.  The power function accessories have mostly traditional Lego style connectors but the Technic has none of those style bricks.

Comment: COuld you add a picture of your model and fitting, or find a picture of the model and indicate where you are putting the motor in?

Comment: It's very difficult to visualise the problem without knowing specifically how the motor and battery pack were installed. Normal (System) Lego bricks are compatible with Technic beams, the studs of a brick are designed to fit into the holes of a Technic beam.